# Как сменить иконки всех маркеров в Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Такой у меня код гугл:

```
function initMap() {
  var firstMarker = {lat: 50.461686, lng:  30.496442};
  var secondMarker = {lat: 50.430365, lng:  30.520543};
  var thirdMarker = {lat: 50.452029, lng:  30.486235};

  // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', firstMarker, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', secondMarker, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', thirdMarker, 3],
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.451756, 30.509776),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: '/html/img/map_marker.png',
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

      // console.log(i)
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        console.log(marker);
        if(marker.icon == '/html/img/map_marker.png') {
          marker.setIcon('/html/img/marker_active.png');

        }
        else {
          marker.setIcon('/html/img/map_marker.png');
        }
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
```

Так выглядит это чудо : [клик](http://joxi.ru/82QegD9UzNvd2d)
Так при клике на элемент : [клак](http://joxi.ru/52anO86TaY3nA0)

Мне нужно, что бы при клике на маркер он менялся на красный (как на втором скрине), а все остальные менялись на синий
Сейчас реализована только первая часть, но я не могу понять, как менять картинку остальным маркерам на синий.

Задача: при клике на маркер давать ЭТОМУ маркеру красную картинку, а остальным двум синюю.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике нужно пройтись по всем маркерам, меняя им цвет на базовый, а кликнутому установить другой.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/k29y0uyk/)

```
// Create the locations array
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', 50.461686, 30.496442, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', 50.430365, 30.520543, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', 50.452029, 30.486235, 3],
];

var markers = [];

function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.451756, 30.509776),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|0000CC',
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

      // console.log(i)
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        console.log(marker);

        //marker.setIcon('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|CC0000');

        for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
            markers[j].setIcon('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|0000CC');
        }

                marker.setIcon('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|CC0000');
      }
    })(marker, i));

    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```